# Failed to add saved page to menu bar - wrapper application using electron

Tags: electron, wrapper

I recently follow a project electron on geeksforgeeks: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/create-a-geeksforgeeks-wrapper-application-using-electron/

Here is its code on Github https://github.com/sayantanm19/geeksforgeeks-desktop/blob/master/index.js

The function appenItemToMenu doesn't work, which means I could save pages offline but the savedpagelist on menu bar is always empty ...

Could you try it on your machine and point out the bug?

```
function appendItemToMenu(filename) { 
curr_menu = Menu.getApplicationMenu() 
        .getMenuItemById("saved").submenu 

curr_menu.append( 
    new MenuItem({ 
    label: path.basename(filename, '.html'), 
    click() { 
        console.log('Saved page opened') 
        win.loadFile(savedFolder + path.basename(filename)) 
    } 
    })) 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function appendItemToMenu(filename) {
  const newMenu = Menu.getApplicationMenu()
  curr_menu = newMenu.getMenuItemById('saved').submenu
  curr_menu.append(
    new MenuItem({
      label: path.basename(filename, '.html'),
      click() {
        console.log('Saved page opened')
        win.loadFile(savedFolder + path.basename(filename))
      }
    }))
  Menu.setApplicationMenu(newMenu)
}
```

Update the application menu after change. Any dynamic change or append Item not allowed.

Comment: Thanks that's it!